# Implementing Monthwise Window store in kstream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to implement monthly windows for a kstream. I tried implementing the same Since different number of days in month I was unable to create window store of different sizes. If some one have idea to implement monthly window please help me with this.

This is the piece of code I have implemented

```
 KTable<Windowed<String>, Customer> tableStream =  input.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))).aggregate(() -> new Customer()
                   .withMsisdn(null)
                   .withCustName(null)
                   .withRechargeAmount(0)
                   .withCreatedTime(null),
           //Aggregator
           (k, v, aggV) -> new Customer()
                   .withMsisdn(v.getMsisdn())
                   .withCustName(v.getCustName())
                   .withRechargeAmount(aggV.getRechargeAmount() + v.getRechargeAmount())
                   .withCreatedTime(v.getCreatedTime()),
           //Serializer
           Materialized.<String, Customer, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("cust-store2").withValueSerde(AppSerdes.Customer()));
   tableStream.toStream().foreach(
           (wKey, value) -> log.info("MONTH-WISE "+
                   "Store ID: " + wKey.key() + " Window ID: " + wKey.window().hashCode() +
                   " Window start: " + Instant.ofEpochMilli(wKey.window().start()).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC) +
                   " Window end: " + Instant.ofEpochMilli(wKey.window().end()).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC) +
                   " Count: " + value
           )
   );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately calendar-based windows are not included out-of-the-box in Kafka Streams. There is a [open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10408) that requests this feature.
The root cause for not having calendar-based windows in Kafka Streams is how the window length is encoded in the keys in the window stores.

However, I can imagine that you could implement monthly windows in a custom `KStream#transform()` with a connected key-value-store.

Comment: Glad to help! Could you accept my answer, if you think this was useful? You can always change your mind if somebody else posts a better one.